# Facing error while deploying node.js app on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I am trying to deploy `node.js` app on google cloud but getting following error. I am facing this error since 10th October. don't know how to resolve:

```
Step #2: ERROR: (gcloud.beta.app.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: You do not have permission to act as '[xxxxxxx]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com'
Step #2: - '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo
Step #2:   description: You do not have permission to act as this service account.
Step #2:   resourceName: [xxxxxx]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
Step #2:   resourceType: serviceAccount
Finished Step #2
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

`CloudBuild.yaml`:

```
steps:

- name: node:10.15.1
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']

- name: node:10.15.1
  entrypoint: npm
  args: [ 'run', 'build', '--prod --verbose']

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['beta', 'app', 'deploy', '--version=prod', '--no-cache']


timeout: '4800s'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should grant the `Service Account User` permission to my CI/CD service account.

You can use the console UI or gcloud command:

[Granting, changing, and revoking access to resources](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access)

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
    ${PROJECT_ID}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com \
    --member=serviceAccount:${PROJECT_NUMBER}@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountUser \
    --project=${PROJECT_ID}
```